# Trouble using JavaScript events on submitting a form to validate its fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, forms

I would like to implement a form with fields for which the validation is "real-time" using JavaScript.

In order to do that I used Java events in this way:

**Text field**

*onkeyup*: this is used to send a request that checks if there are errors for this field every time you release a key. If there are errors it will show those, otherwise an "Ok!" text.

**Submit button**

*onclick*:  when clicked, this will check *again* if there are errors. If so, this will show errors, otherwise it will hide the submit button.

At the end of the page I have a JavaScript that will *focus* a Text Field when show up.

Using simultaneously *onkeyup* and *focus* events on the field, after the form is submitted WITHOUT click the button (event related to the button happens only when the button is clicked, not when I use the 'enter' key [on keyboard] to submit the form), the *focus* event will trigger automatically the *onkeyup* event: this means that, after submitting, are called two events (*focus* implies *onkeyup*) and so for the Text Field will be displayed first the errors, if there are, and then the "Ok!" text.

**I would like to not *focus* on the field after submitting the form so the *onkeyup* event will be not triggered... or use the 'enter' key to simulate the 'click' of the submit button.**

---

P.S.: if you know other techniques to perform validation in "real-time" (and better), let me know.

Comment: Could you please read through your question again and make it better understandable? Esp. things like `and so for the Text Field will be displayed first the errors, if there are, and then the "Ok!" text.`. You never mentioned an “Ok!” text before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/) and the [**JQuery validation plugin**](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) will save you heaps of time in terms of implementing live validation.

You can also combine them with the  [**JQuery Form plugin**](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to check validation on (before, technically) submit.